# No color with Epson xp-440 on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, printing

I downloaded and installed the epson driver. I did System>Printers>Add Printer>Add Network Printer and Ubuntu found and installed the epson xp-440 using "driverless cups filters". When I print a test page, it prints fine except it is only black and white! Everything else works fine - it scans, shows ink levels, etc. just no color! Any ideas??

Comment: Install linux printer from Epson site. http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Comment: The epson download page has 3 different drivers, 2 for printer and 1 for scanner. I downloaded and installed all 3. Still no color.

Comment: All 3 is not a good idea. But this means that the printer is broken. Check the driver settings too. Or you did not install drivers properly. Did you remove and install the printer again after you installed the drivers? There are 2 alternative printer drivers and 1 scanner one.

Comment: I was not correct. All 3 was the right choice in this case.

Comment: Very interesting. I deleted the printer and it kept popping back up. Turning the printer off caused it to disappear. Turning it on (without doing anything else) causes it to reappear. When I right click and choose "properties" I get two error messages, "Error print quality is set to 0 and cannot be edited" and "Error page orientation is set to 0 and cannot be edited." Then it loads the "properties" and everything seems normal, but the test page still comes out black & white. FWIW using the 'copy' function, the printer does color just fine so at least I know the printer isn't broken.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure why this is working, but while the printer was turned off, I went through the steps of Add Printer > Select Device > Epson Inject printer #1 appears as a choice, so choose that > Choose Driver from database > Epson > XP-440 > choose the 'escpr', not the driverless cups choice and finish install. When I turn the printer on, the "Epson XP-440 Series on local host" still appears as another printer, but if I print to the Epson XP-440 and NOT to EPSON6612.local, everything works and it is in color. Not really an ideal situation as the .local printer comes and goes depending on whether the printer is on or off, but the 'escpr' printer works, so I'm OK with it!

Answer (score 0):

The new automatic printer installation system in Zesty has some severe problems so for now we just have to add printers the old fashioned way.

The first thing to do is disable automatic printer installation by executing the following commands:

sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed; sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed

The first command stops the printer installation daemon, the second command permanently prevents it from starting at boot.

Now open your normal printer installation dialog (In Xubuntu Zesty it's Settings->Printer). Delete any printers that were previously automatically installed, click on "Add", and then the tiny down arrow next to "Network Printer".

You'll immediately see your printer with a .local extension but be careful!, it's not the one you want! Wait another few seconds and you'll see another entry for your printer with an IP address (like 192.168.1.10 or something), that's the one you want.

Now click on the printer and select "LPD/LPR queue 'PASSTHRU'" in the column that appears on the right. Depending on your printer it might say something a little different, but hopefully LPD or LPR is in there somewhere.

Now click "Forward". If you're asked further about the driver select ESC/PR, but often you're not asked. Now just click "Apply" and viola!, you have a color printer again!